# How to copy a file from a local machine to a linux server using bash

Tags: linux, bash, virtual-machine

I have a file on my local machine and want to copy it to the Linux server. I know I can do this online(through mail or dropbox for example), but think that there must be easier ways to do so. Is there a Bash command to do this right from the linux server?

Comment: Have you tried to google this problem first? What did you find? What didn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scp` (secure copy; part of ssh) is what is commonly used for this.

```
scp myfile.txt myserveruseraccount@myserver.example.com:/path/on/server/
```

Note that like most Unix commands, `scp` is a general Unix command, not specifically a `bash` built-in command. It can be invoked from any shell, not just `bash`.